# In Android, BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray returns null for RGBA byte array

Tags: android, bitmap, arrays

I am implementing a Xamarin Android application which does some image manipulation. I am loading a Bitmap, converting it to an RGBA byte array (4 bytes per pixel), and then I want to reconvert this byte array into a Bitmap.

Because of the nature of the pixel manipulation I am doing, I do NOT want to deal with JPEG or PNG compressed byte arrays. It has to be RGBA.

Here is some code which demonstrates my issue, reduced to the minimum:

```
var size = bitmap.Height * bitmap.RowBytes;
var buffer = ByteBuffer.Allocate(size);
bitmap.CopyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);

buffer.Rewind();

var bytes = new byte[size];
buffer.Get(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

// At this point, bytes is an RGBA byte array, and I verified
// that the bytes are consistent with the image.

// Why doesn't this work?
var bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

// Or this?
var imageStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
var bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(imageStream);
```

What is the way in Android to recreate a Bitmap from an RGBA byte array?

Complement of information: In iOS, I used CGBitmapContext with an RGB color space (CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB()). In Windows 10, I used a WriteableBitmap. What's the equivalent in Android?

Thanks
Laurent

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [Bitmap.copyPixels](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copyPixelsFromBuffer(java.nio.Buffer)) to write pixels from a buffer to a `Bitmap`, like so

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
```

Also as you *already* have a `Bitmap` there should be very little reason for you to copy it. If you really do need to copy it you can just do it like so

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap);
```

The reason `BitmapFactory.DecodeXXX` does not work is because they expect an encoded image, while you have a pixel buffer that is *not* encoded. This is the opposite from what the functions expect. Instead use the example above.

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't this work?

`BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray` and `BitmapFactory.DecodeStream` still requires all the headers of an image which `copyPixelsToBuffer` does not copy. Without these it can't tell the image encoding (bitmap, jpeg, png etc), or the width, height and bits per pixel.

The complimentary function to `copyPixelsToBuffer` is [`copyPixelsFromBuffer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copyPixelsFromBuffer(java.nio.Buffer)).